# Providing up Navigation for new Toolbar in Navigation Drawer?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar, appcompatactivity

i'm using new `Toolbar` and my question is how to provide `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled` for Navigation Drawer?

Usually i do when i use old `ActionBar` by,

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

But when i use the same in new `toolbar`, it says

> Method Invocation
>   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); may cause Null
>   Pointer Exception.

[image]

And i should know how to achieve the above in Fragment as i'm now using Fragment for re-using purpose.

Answer (score 2):

`getSupportActionBar()` simply might be `null`.

Avoid any possible error by checking what `getSupportActionBar()` returns:

```
final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
if (actionBar != null) {
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: Since i use new Toolbar, i 've to declare `NoActionBar` in theme. So, i've to done in a different way. This doesn't really solves my problem.

Comment: If using the new `Toolbar` then make sure to call `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#setSupportActionBar(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar)

Comment: I've added that code. That is in above the line of posted code.

Comment: If you check for it to be `null`, you cannot have this error. Just check `if actionBar != null`...

Comment: It doesn't throws NPE error. It says 'may produce'. You can see that error in my question. The point is, it doesn't show up caret because i can't set this code.

Comment: Of course there is no NPE... The IDE says it "might" if you let it without check. It will **never** complain if you check it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an ActionBarActivity then you can tell Android to use the Toolbar as the ActionBar with your current code.

For back navigation on fragments use this:

```
((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Make sure your fragment is added to back stack using:

```
.addToBackStack("Tag")
```

In your fragment transaction.

If you're not using an ActionBarActivity add an back arrow drawable icon to your toolbar and use this:

```
mActionBar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_back));
mActionBar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //What to do on back clicked
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

And what is problem here? If you use support Toolbar (`android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` in xml layout) and you forget to call `setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);` before `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` of course you will get `Null Pointer Exception`. If you set it then there is nothing to worry about...